# Pickit J3 expansion header pinout

Tags: pic, pickit

I am trying to find out a diagram for pickit1 J3 header, it is not in the manual and I was not able to search it on google. I wonder if somone have it to share here.

Thanks.

Comment: Which PICkit do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 14-pin, 2.54mm (0.1") pitch (single row) receptacle. Here it is in the [manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40051D.pdf) (page 35):

[image: 14-pin recep]

Molex, Tyco and others make these.
Here is a picture of the board with it present:

[image: PicKit1]

Here is an [example](http://uk.farnell.com/samtec/ces-114-01-t-s/receptacle-2-54mm-single-14way/dp/1667519) from Farnell (pic below), and the [page](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=2031%20203441%20110195024&Ns=P_PRICE_FARNELL_UK%7C0&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=14%20receptacle&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial&locale=en_UK&appliedparametrics=true&getResults=true&suppressRedirect=true&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=2031%2b203441&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=14%2breceptacle&Ntx=mode%2bmatchallpartial&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&prevNValues=2031%2b203441) it came from with other options.

[image: 14-pin receptacle]